# Import file problem when using python tools/test.py command

Tags: python, import

I want to import some functions using code

```
from mmdet.datasets.builder import (build_dataloader, build_dataset)
```

the path `mmdet.datasets.builder` is under my project file, but when running the code, it seems the system import functions from `lustre/home/acct-medcb/medcb-cb1/.conda/envs/Swin/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mmdet/datasets/builder.py`,this is in my conda environment.
How can I modify my code to import functions right from the path I specified instead of using the same function from conda environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `sys.path` to add the path that you want to import from:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(1, '<your specified path>')
from builder import (build_dataloader, build_dataset)
```